# how to get all the array values for a given descendant in a Json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

```
    {
  "hasLoadMore": true,
  "groups": [
    {
      "order": 0,
      "title": "string",
      "total": 0,
      "dateFormat": "string",
      "messages": [
        {
          "commsId": 0,
          "commsDirectionCode": "string",
          "commsReasonCRSNN": 0,
          "commsDeliveryChannelCDCHN": "string",
          "commsDeliveryStateCode": "string",
          "commsDeliveryDttm": "2017-02-14T02:20:52.836Z",
          "commsSuccessFlag": true,
          "commsCode": "string",
          "commsName": "string",
          "commsRankingNumb": 0,
          "customerGrainCUSGN": 0,
          "productItemCode": "string",
          "sourceApplBAPPN": 0,
          "sourceCommsRefn": "string",
          "parentCommsId": 0,
          "campaignDttm": "2017-02-14T02:20:52.836Z",
          "campaignCode": "string",
          "campaignName": "string",
          "contentValidStartDttm": "2017-02-14T02:20:52.836Z",
          "contentValidEndDttm": "2017-02-14T02:20:52.836Z",
          "trackingCode": "string",
          "headlineDisplayText": "string",
          "contentDisplayText": "string",
          "topic": "string",
          "topicIconClass": "string",
          "contentTemplateId": 0,
          "contentTemplateVersNumb": 0,
          "archiveDate": "2017-02-14T02:20:52.836Z",
          "commsParameters": [
            {
              "commsId": 0,
              "paramSeqNumb": 0,
              "paramText": "string",
              "paramValue": "string"
            }
          ],
          "contentTemplateParameters": [
            {
              "commsId": 0,
              "paramSeqNumb": 0,
              "paramText": "string",
              "paramValue": "string"
            }
          ],
          "callToAction": [
            {
              "displayText": "string",
              "uri": "string"
            }
          ],
          "isFlagged": true,
          "isSeen": true,
          "isRead": true,
          "isActioned": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

my json is above , now i have multiple `'callToActions'` array in the above json and want to collect all of them and compare with a table.

what i am doing is below:

```
 {

        string content = Context.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        var resultObjects = AllChildren(JObject.Parse(content))
        .First(c => c.Type == JTokenType.Array && c.Path.Contains(decendant))
        .Children<JObject>();
        JArray responseList = new JArray();
        foreach (JObject result in resultObjects)
        {
           responseList.Add(result);

        }
        CompareObjectToTable(responseList, table);

    }

     private static IEnumerable<JToken> AllChildren(JToken decendant)
    {
        foreach (var c in decendant.Children())
        {
            yield return c;
            foreach (var cc in AllChildren(c))
            {
                yield return cc;
            }
        }
    }
```

But it will only give me the `"First"` array encountered but i want to gather all the array(multiple) with same descendant.Here descendant i want is `callToActions`

Comment: You could parse it and get the whole thing in one swipe

Answer (score 3):

Rather than hand-coding your own method to recursively descend the `JToken` hierarchy, you can use the built-in methods [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm) or [`JToken.SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) to do it for you.

Using the first approach, you would do:

```
var root = (JContainer)JToken.Parse(content);
var descendant = "callToAction";
var query = root
    // Recursively descend the JSON hierarchy
    .DescendantsAndSelf()
    // Select all properties named descendant
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == descendant)
    // Select their value
    .Select(p => p.Value)
    // And filter for those that are arrays.
    .OfType<JArray>();
```

And using the second approach:

```
var root = JToken.Parse(content);
var descendant = "callToAction";
var query = root
    // Recursively descend the JSON hierarchy using the JSONpath recursive descent operator "..", and select the values of all properties named descendant
    .SelectTokens(string.Format("..{0}", descendant))
    // And filter for those that are arrays.
    .OfType<JArray>();
```

Note that I am using the [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) recursive descent operator `".."` to descend the hierarchy. Json.NET's `SelectTokens()` method [supports JSONPath query syntax](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) which is somewhat similar to XPath.

Now, it's not clear from your question whether `responseList` should be an array of arrays of results, or a flat array of results.  To create an array of arrays, just do:

```
var responseList = new JArray(query);
```

To create a flattened array, do:

```
var responseList = new JArray(query.SelectMany(a => a));
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/harQ5y).