# Get value in Nested JSON/JTOKEN using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq, jsonparser

I am new to `LINQ` queries and would like to know if what I am trying to achieve is possible via `LINQ` query.

So, I have a JSON doc as below.

I am trying to get all the values that  match the **"$type"** and return me the directory path and the value for $type.

I know an interactive way of doing this but it seems LINQ is preferred and supposed to be easy to get this.

```
{
   "$type":"type1",
   "title":"US version",
   "_object1":[
      {
         "$type":"type2",
         "rootModule":{
            "id":"page",
            "modules":[
               {
                  "id":"header",
                  "$type":"module-header"
               },
               {
                  "id":"footer",
                  "$type":"module-footer"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "$type":"type2",
         "_id":"ab134"
      },
      {
         "$type":"type3",
         "_id":"ab567"
      }
   ],
   "_object2":[
      {
         "$type":"module1",
         "constraintsId":"page"
      },
      {
         "name":"header1 1",
         "nestedobject":{
            "$type":"nestedobject-type",
            "dataBinder":{
               "id":"ab244"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: `I am trying to get all the values`  can we see that part?

Comment: Hi @Plutonix , I need all the values from the JSON that has the key  as "$type".  Does that explains?

Comment: You mean something like this?  [Parse json without full path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29493462).

Comment: A JSONPath query is also a possibility, see [How do I get a deeply-nested property from JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36324494) or [how to get all the array values for a given descendant in a Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42333667).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys,

I was able to get the list as below:

```
    var root = (JContainer)JToken.FromObject(document, CommonSerializerSetting.GetCommonSerializer());
    var descendant = "$type";
    var query = root

        // Recursively descend the JSON hierarchy
        .DescendantsAndSelf()

        // Select all properties named descendant
        .OfType<JProperty>()
        .Where(p => p.Name == descendant)

        // Select their value
        .Select(p => p.Value);
```